# Failed to establish websocket connection: HOSTNAME_UNVERIFIED

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, discord, discord-jda

I realized the problem yesterday, when my discord bots instead of playing music started to join and leave the voicechannel rapidly. I checked the log and this error was spammed in there:

```
[JDA AudioWS-ConnectThread (guildId: 388969412889411585)] WARN net.dv8tion.jda.core.audio.AudioWebSocket - Failed to establish websocket connection: HOSTNAME_UNVERIFIED - The certificate of the peer (CN=*.discord.gg, OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard, OU=Domain Control Validated) does not match the expected hostname (eu-west791.discord.media)
Closing connection and attempting to reconnect.
```

My bots are running on a Raspberry Pi 3.

I haven't changed the code for about a week and after the last update the bots still worked. I haven't updated any software on my pi for a fair amount of time.
My best guess was restarting the pi and voilá, it worked. For about 10 minutes (I'm not exactly sure about this number) until it broke again.
After that I updated both JDA and Lavaplayer to the latest stable versions available (JDA to 1.8.3_464 and Lavaplayer to 1.3.18).
No changes, the problem still existed.
Then I tried updating java on my pi from

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

to

```
openjdk version "9-Raspbian"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Raspbian+0-9b181-4bpo9rpt1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 9-Raspbian+0-9b181-4bpo9rpt1, mixed mode)
```

(I hope a didn't frick it up. I'm still relatively new to working with rpis and Ubuntu in general.)
Still not working.
(EDIT: The problem is definitely the pi, since I started the pi on my windows laptop and it worked fine.)

I would be glad if someone could explain to me what exactly went wrong with my bots and would show me a solution (I'm a beginner, if you provide a tutorial or explain something step-by-step I would be very pleased.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both of your JRE versions are severely outdated and probably don't support SNI.

Comment: @Minn Do you know how to update it on a raspberry pi? (How did it work before? Or did something change in the past few days?)

Comment: Your JDA version is also very outdated. The current version right now is in the 4.x.x. You should probably update the bot to those, though it will require some rewriting. Support for the old versions doesn't exist anymore.

EDIT: I just realized that this was sent in July of 2019... Why is StackOverflow showing me thse questions?